# cannot find the animation running in create-js, no errors listed

Tags: javascript, animation, createjs

I am using sprite-sheet animation in create js with prototype.when i am doing it alone its working fine but when i am integrating it in project the animations are not visible and no error is listed in console. please see to the fiddle to understand my question.`here is the js fiddle link`[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gopalravi/74hgtvL4/4/)

when i am running this code separately its working fine .but when implemented inside my project the animations are not visible. and no errors are shown in console.

[downpot][2][pot1][3]

[pot2][4]

Comment: can you add the image to the fiddle? It can simple be a problem of scaling, that the object is drawn/animated out of bounds.

Comment: Additionally, you only need the one Ticker listener (you have 3). It shouldn't break anything, but you don't want to update your stage 3 times every tick.

Comment: @taran I have added the image

Comment: @lanny I can't understand . and now in this fiddle its working fine ,but when i am adding additional canvas i:e stage  in my project with this code its not working and not showing errors too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/t4a2cdbc/

My changes:

- I use a single container, which makes the whole animation set easier to move around. This is called `this.container`, and all children are added to it. This removes all the "lc" containers.
- I renamed the animations instead to `lc1`, `lc2`, and `lc3`. They are stored as variables on the PotChips instance for easy reference. They are added to the same container.
- When creating the instances, I use a local variable "lc", which is ONLY used in the local function: `var lc = this.lc1 = new ...etc`
- I passed `this` as the 3rd parameter of the `lc.on()` method, which calls the method in the scope of the PotChips instance. This means you can refer to any of the instance's properties using `this`.
- I removed the redundant Ticker listeners. You just need one, which is now in the constructor.
- I got rid of the "run" 2nd parameter of the SpriteSheet. This is the "first animation/frame" argument, which the original "grant running" SpriteSheet demo uses. Instead I immediately call `lc.gotoAndPlay(0)`. You should be able to use the frame names, but they aren't working for some reason - which I will look into further.
- I got rid of all the x/y params on the lc instances. You might want to add them back in with the right values.
- I changed the spritesheet image to use HTTPS to avoid the console errors

This isn't perfect (the first 2 animations don't seem to get removed at the right time), but it should be a good start, and show you how some of these issues can be solved.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for the help..will try this in my code

Comment: @ lanny :the code you gave is working fine , but when i integrate it with my angularjs project its not working, no errors are displayed in console and the animations are not visible . should i add extra code to make it work with angularjs?????. If I am using separate canvas for each canvas,the animations are visible, but for a single canvas for all functions is not working.

Comment: I would have to see the code in action to figure out what is going on.

Comment: sure, I will create a new fiddle and post it soon. thank you very much for the continuous support.